# setup.py develop not respecting package kwarg

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

My folder structure looks like

```
.
├── my_package
│   ├── A.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── my_package2
│   ├── B.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

And my setup.py looks like

```
from setuptools import setup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(name='my_packages',
          packages=['my_package'])
```

When I run

```
python3 setup.py develop
```

The egg file is created locally and an egg-link file is placed in my `site-packages` directory. Also, the folder is added to `easy_install.pth` which means that both `my_package` and `my_package2` are importable. This is different than running `python3 setup.py install` (only `my_package` would be available per the keyword argument passed to the setup function).

This same behavior occurs when installing with `pip` using the `-e` flag.

Is this intended behavior? Is there any way to replicate the functionality of `install` using `develop`?

Comment: If `my_package2` shouldn't be available, what is it doing there? Is it used by `my_package`?

Comment: In this case it's nothing (was just learning how setup.py). But I suppose it could be a package for testing.

Comment: In that case, you probably do want the tests available when developing. I found [this article](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/) useful for getting a project set up for distribution.